# UPDATE STATEMENT in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am using asp.net with C# as code behind

```
   OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Documents and Settings\CJP\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\WebSites\NewElligibleSoft\elligiblity.mdb;Persist Security Info=False");
        cn.Open();
        string sql = "UPDATE main SET s_name='"+TextBox1.Text+"',inst_code='"+DropDownList1.SelectedItem+"',ms_oms='"+Label7.Text+"',elligiblity='"+Label12.Text+"',Board='"+DropDownList5.SelectedItem+"',percentage='"+TextBox4.Text+"' WHERE elg_id = '"+DropDownList4.SelectedItem+"'";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, cn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Dispose();
        cn.Close();
        Response.Write("alert('DATA UPDATED')");
```

i am getting error on

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

that Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Answer (score 4):

Don't code like

```
string connection_string="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Documents and Settings\CJP\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\WebSites\NewElligibleSoft\elligiblity.mdb;Persist Security Info=False";
using(OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(connection_string))
{
     cn.Open();
     string sql = "UPDATE main SET s_name=?,inst_code=?,ms_oms=?,elligiblity=?,Board=?,percentage=?,amount=? WHERE elg_id =?";

     using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, cn))
     {
          cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("s_name",TextBox1.Text.Trim()));
          cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("inst_code",DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString()));
          cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("ms_oms",Label7.Text.ToString()));
          cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("elligiblity",Label12.Text));
          cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("Board",DropDownList5.SelectedItem.Value.ToString()));
          cmd.Parameters.Add(new  OleDbParameter("percentage",DropDownList5.SelectedItem.Value.ToString()));
          cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(amount",DropDownList5.SelectedItem.Value.ToString()));
          cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("elg_id",DropDownList5.SelectedItem.Value.ToString()));
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          cn.Close();
     }
}        
 Response.Write("alert('DATA UPDATED')");
```

Comment: hey, you are right that code 'does' work but its not recommended.
Cheers.

Comment: Yeah, sure depending on your database you just need to change the binding parameters. In Sql Server we use '@parameterName' instead of '?'.Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text` or `DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value`

This should be the same for all DropDownLists.

Also you might have to convert TextBox4 to the appropriate datatype for "percentage".

Assuming that the percentage is a Double, you'd need something like

`Double.Parse(Textbox4.Text)`

Lastly, if you're not sending a "string" to the query, you would be really good to remove the single quotes from those fields. That way you're not parsing the data but still sending string information.

Comment: again, you basically need to convert (parse) all of your inputs (textboxes and dropdownlists) into the appropriate data types before submitting the query.

Answer (score 1):

Remove single quotes around `DropDownList4.SelectedItem`. I bet your `elg_id` column is of type integer or something, and you're giving it a string.

Having that said, you would be really better off if you provided text of error, database table structure and maybe some other information so that people wouldn't have to read your mind.

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer helped you, would you please consider accepting it? (just click that hollow checkmark to the left)

Answer (score 0):

this is de correct code

```
OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Documents and Settings\CJP\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\WebSites\NewElligibleSoft\elligiblity.mdb;Persist Security Info=False");
        cn.Open();
        string sql = "UPDATE main SET s_name='" + TextBox1.Text + "',inst_code='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() + "',ms_oms='" + Label7.Text + "',elligiblity='" + Label12.Text + "',Board='" + DropDownList5.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() + "',percentage='" + float.Parse(TextBox4.Text) + "',amount='" + Label10.Text + "' WHERE elg_id = " + DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Value + "";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, cn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Dispose();
        cn.Close();
        Response.Write("alert('DATA UPDATED')");
```

thanxx

Answer (score 0):

```
OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Documents and Settings\CJP\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\WebSites\NewElligibleSoft\elligiblity.mdb;Persist Security Info=False");
        cn.Open();
        string sql = "UPDATE main SET s_name='" + TextBox1.Text + "',inst_code='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() + "',ms_oms='" + Label7.Text + "',elligiblity='" + Label12.Text + "',Board='" + DropDownList5.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() + "',percentage='" + float.Parse(TextBox4.Text) + "',amount='" + Label10.Text + "' WHERE elg_id = " + DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Value + "";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, cn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Dispose();
        cn.Close();
        Response.Write("alert('DATA UPDATED')");
```

Comment: Welcome on SO! Please write a small statement in your answer on where the error was and how you fixed it. That makes your answer better understandable for other readers.